# WooCommerce Parent Order Prefix

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, prefix

I am trying to achieve an order prefix between "Parent Order" and "Sub Orders". Currently I have the order prefix's working for products in specific categories, so 'Merchandise' Categories and products within have the order number prefix 'M' and the Categories and products within 'Coffee' have the prefix 'C', this all works fine, brilliantly see the image attached.

I do have subscription products and single products within the store but I mainly just want the one 'P' to show up for the main order regardless of the category the product is within.

I need and would like help adding for the parent order a 'P' so that I can distinguish between Parent and sub orders, (please see attached image) I cannot for the life of me figure out this function currently my code is this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );
function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $category = array();
    if ( ! empty($order) ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
            $parent_id = $order->get_parent_id( $parent, 'product_id' );
            if ( ! empty($terms) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $category[] = $term->term_id; 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $parent ) {
    $order_id = 'P - '. $order_id;
    } else {
        if ( in_array( 23, $category ) ) {
            $order_id = 'M - '. $order_id;
        } else {
            if ( in_array( 16, $category ) ) {
                $order_id = 'C - '. $order_id;
            }
        }
        return $order_id;
    }
}
```

The 'M' & 'C' work perfectly... just the parent order 'P' does not so instead of a 'P' I have what seems to be a random M or C in the parent order section. All my orders split in categories and this still works as expected (please see image). I mainly just need the 'P' Main Parent order on the left from the image attached

[Parent Order Prefix 'P' Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QE8Ur.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `$parent` variable in the `$parent_id = $order->get_parent_id( $parent, 'product_id' );` line is not set or initialized. Perhaps the problem lies with that.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo thank you very much for your input, erm... so I am totally brand new at this and most the code I used above I reused from this website anyways, how would I go about setting or initialising the $parent object. I feel I would have to do as I've done with the $parent_id setting, you've mentioned but do something similar for $parent?

Comment: You should explain the logic. When should the "P" prefix be assigned? Edit your question and [enter all the minimum information necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to allow others to understand and solve your problem.

Comment: Do you use a plugin? WooCommerce does not handle sub orders by default.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, thank you for your response, I do use a plugin, it is called "Multi Order for WooCommerce Pro"

Answer (score 0):

You are currently returning the order number only within the else statement.

> A value should always be returned at the end of the function.

Also the `$parent` variable **is not set** and you are getting the parent id the wrong way.

Try this, hope it works.

The [**`get_parent_id()`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-abstracts-abstract-wc-order.html#source-view.275) method returns `0` if the function has no parent order.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );
function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $category = array();
    if ( ! empty($order) ) {
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id'];
            $terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
            if ( ! empty($terms) ) {
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    $category[] = $term->term_id; 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $parent_id = $order->get_parent_id();

    if ( $parent_id > 0 ) {
        if ( in_array( 23, $category ) ) {
            $order_id = 'M - '. $order_id;
        } else {
            if ( in_array( 16, $category ) ) {
                $order_id = 'C - '. $order_id;
            }
        }
    } else {
        $order_id = 'P - '. $order_id;
    }
    return $order_id;
}
```

Also you could optimize the function like this:

```
// change the WooCommerce order number
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_number', 'change_woocommerce_order_number' );
function change_woocommerce_order_number( $order_id ) {

    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $prefix = '';
    $has_cat_id_23 = false;
    $has_cat_id_16 = false;

    // get the parent order id
    $parent_id = $order->get_parent_id();

    // if it does not have a parent order it returns the order number with the prefix "P - "
    if ( $parent_id == 0 ) {
        $prefix = 'P - ';
        return $prefix . $order_id;
    // otherwise set the prefix to the child orders
    } else {
        
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            // if the product belongs to the product category with ID 23
            if ( has_term( 23, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                $has_cat_id_23 = true;
                break;
            }
            // if the product belongs to the product category with ID 16
            if ( has_term( 16, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
                $has_cat_id_16 = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // if the product belongs to the product category with ID 23 set the prefix "M - "
        if ( $has_cat_id_23 ) {
            $prefix = 'M - ';
        }
    
        // if the product belongs to the product category with ID 16 set the prefix "C - "
        if ( $has_cat_id_16 ) {
            $prefix = 'C - ';
        }
    }

    return $prefix . $order_id;
}
```

The code has been tested and works (*I didn't install the plugin but actually only used Wordpress and WooCommerce functions and methods)*. The result will look like:

[image]

Try it out and let me know if it works for you too.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, thank you very much for that piece of code, I mean the P is showing, which I couldn't get to work myself, it is the suborders however, which are the main chunks that need to fall into place now. All suborders (product categories) are showing up as P also, regardless of category. I am not quite sure how to add an image here in this comment but I will play around with your code also as I'm excited about the P :) thank you.

Comment: The only control I have set is the parent order id. Can you make sure that the suborders have a parent order id and that it is greater than zero? Otherwise I didn't understand something. Also what piece of code have you tried?